# Random Number doesn't print the result

Tags: html, vue.js, button, random

I'm trying to get a random number when cliking a button and I'm doing something wrong, it works with another example that doesn't have a function so I must be doing something wrong but can't find what. Right now it prints the function code as text.

This is the html:

```
<div id="aleatori">
   <button v-on:click="randomNumber">Aleatori</button>
   <p>{{ randomNumber }}</p>
</div>
```

This is the js

```
var aleatori = new Vue({
    el:'#aleatori',
    data: {
        randomNumber: function () {
            this.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1
          }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call a method `onclick` and change `random` in `data` as follows:

```js
var aleatori = new Vue({
    el:'#aleatori',
    data() {
        return{
              random:0
        }
    },
    methods:{
      randomNumber() {
            this.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="aleatori">
     <button v-on:click="randomNumber">Aleatori</button>
     <p>{{ random }}</p>
</div>
```